# Ionic 3 FireReader not working but Ionic 4 can

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I built my Ionic project on two different computers and got different result.

The first computer: Ionic Info

> Ionic:
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
>      Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
>      @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
>
> Cordova:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
>      Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1
>      Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (19 plugins total)
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v8.11.3 (/usr/bin/node)
>      npm    : 6.2.0
>      OS     : Linux 4.15

FileReader only work when I put await in reader.readAsDataURL();

The second computer:

> Ionic info
>
> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
> Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```

my code:

```
async downloadFromURL(fileName, mimeType, url){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        try{
            var self = this;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.responseType='blob';  
            xhr.onloadend = async function(e) {
                if (xhr.status == 200)
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = async function(event){
                        var response = self.insertFile({
                            'type': mimeType,
                            'title': fileName
                        }, event.target["result"].split(',')[1]);
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                    await reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        } catch (error) {
            reject();
            console.log("error", error);
        }
    });
}
```

So, my question is how can I fix this without update ionic and cordova?

And sorry for my bad english :D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your `index.html` try moving the script tag for `cordova.js` from the header to the body, below the `build/polyfills.js` script tag. My body tag now looks like this:

```
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Apparently this is a known issue with zones.js, according to [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sometimes-the-filereader-does-not-response/138771).